# Database schema export

Tags: data-export, database, schema, schema-builder, backup

Hi we have a date export made from salesforce instance.
We'd like to rebuild just the database but we stumbled on process to import the CSV files to a SQL Server database.
We have force.com IDE eclipse plugin, although give you schema explorer there's no way to export this?
ERD Tool - I dont need visual I need solid data like xml to rebuild schema.
Data loader - no option like this
Salesforce - schema builder no option.

ATM we check schemaspy & backup-force.com - but it's so frustrating you can export schema that....

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for exactly. You can use Eclipse.IDE / Metadata API to retrieve XML which represents the objects in your org. In other words, includes the field definitions etc. You can use dataloader etc. to pull the records out.

Comment: If you mean that you want to replicate the schema and data into a SQL Server database, then there are commercial tools that do that.

Comment: For example, we use Informatica for this task

Answer (score 1):

There are few Apex exchange tools which can do that for you and also if partners could have build it, there should be a way for the customers to also build it.

Please check the below links which might help you.

https://code.google.com/p/copyforce/

http://sfdc.arrowpointe.com/2007/08/09/replicate-salesforce-schema-to-oracle-or-mysql/

http://www.mydbsync.com/integration/cloud-replication-for-salesforce

http://www.talendforge.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=30961